# Pagination or navigation control in Windows Phone 8.1 app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

i am developing windows phone 8.1 app

i have define navigation path on top of every page. but as my path grow, size does not fit my screen. currently i am searching a control to shorttern my path

please refer below image

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own converter that truncates the string to a given maximal length

```
public class MaxStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public MaxStringConverter()
    {
        ReplaceChars = "...";
        MaxLenght = int.MaxValue;
    }

    public int MaxLength { get; set; }
    public string ReplaceChars { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string culture)
    {
        string val = (string)value;
        int replaceCharLength = ReplaceChars.Length;
        if(val.Lenght > MaxLength )
        {
            int middle = val.Lenght / 2;
            int textLenth = MaxLength - 2 * replaceCharLength;
            string textToReturn = val.Substring(middle - replaceCharLength , textLenth);
            return string.Format("{1}{0}{1}", textToReturn, ReplaceChars);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as

```
<Window.Resources>
    <MaxStringConverter x:Key="MaxStringConverter" MaxLength=100/>
</Window.Resources>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyText, Converter={StaticResource MaxStringConverter}}"/>
```